# Adding multiple data in select option rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, select

I am using bellow code and function **options_from_collection_for_select** for generating options for user.

```
<%= select_tag 'receiver', options_from_collection_for_select(@user, 'id', 'email')  %>
```

Above code generate bellow html:

```
<select id="receiver" name="receiver" style="display: none;">
   <option value="1">email1@yahoo.com</option>
   <option value="2">email2@gmail.com</option>
   <option value="3">email3@gmail.com</option>
</select>
```

But i want email with username, e.g `<optionvalue="1">email1@yahoo.com(some_user)</option>`

Suggestion any alternate function or customize current function will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `User` model add a method :

```
def user_dispay_name
  "#{email}(#{full_name})"
end
```

Now do :

```
<%= select_tag 'receiver', options_from_collection_for_select(@user, 'id', 'user_dispay_name')  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

But without `options_from_collection_for_select` this function i'm using below code:

```
<%= select_tag 'receiver', options_for_select(@user.map{ |c| ["#{c.email} (#{c.display_name})", "#{c.id}"] })   %>
```